# What is the best way to handle periodic timeouts when targeting Azure SQL Serverless tier Db?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

We moved from DTU to Serverless tier and our configuration is set as:

1. Tier: General Purpose Serverless
2. Minimum vCore: 4
3. Maximum vCore: 14
4. Region: West Europe
5. Backup: Locally redundant [we have a failover setup, do not use backups]

The core values above are result of a query from Microsoft which gave recommendation about the range of vCore to opt for.

The reason I am asking here is, inspite of the configurations working reliably, we see frequent down-grade in the Db resources and our APIs experience SQL timeout causing systems to not recover in time.

[image: CPU Percentage]

We have background services which run every 30 mins and can say that there is optimal load on the Db 24x7, 365 days but not anything intense.

Is there something specific we should look into? Any tips to help us understand why the Db goes below certain point and takes about 2-3 mins to resume before the APIs get normal.

At the moment, our temporary action is to **swap the API slots** to recover from connection issues.

If it matters when we have check from the API under Diagnostics, we see **SNAT port exhaustion**, to which, we have **setup VNET** between the API app service and SQL resource. This was after we faced the issue and have not seen the issue yet.

We are actively trying to see if something specific in code can be improved, but also want to seek advice if we can do something specific about the Db availability.

This is happening to us randomly since last 3 weeks without a specific pattern.

Comment: You should edit the title into something that describes the *actual* problem. You aren't asking how to monitor the database, you're asking how to handle periodic timeouts.

Comment: Besides, serverless means you're using shared resources and the service can decide to scale up or down based on the actual load. That can take minutes and drop queries [according to the Azure SQL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose#scaling-responsiveness). AWS's Aurora only needs milliseconds though and won't drop queries, which prompted Brent Ozar to [write about this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2023/04/what-sql-server-people-should-know-about-amazon-aurora-serverless/).

Comment: Which means, what you experience may be Azure SQL's normal behavior. You'll have to rewrite your code to handle such interruptions, eg using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient's [configurable retry logic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/configurable-retry-logic-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient/). Serverless scenarios are mentioned explicitly in the article

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction about the question @PanagiotisKanavos. We are looking into the retry logic, will share updates as we test it out.

Comment: What kind of support contract do you have with Azure? Seems like a support engineer should be able to tell you if something is actually wrong here or you just need to use a different SKU because serverless won't meet your performance requirements

Comment: Thanks Martin, we have Standard support plan. Have raised a ticket and awaiting response.